# SQLite3 UPDATE error in python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sql-update

I am getting an "Operator error near "?"" error when I run the following SQL statement;

```
    key = 'field_a'
    value = '01/01/2011'
    #self.testac = '010101010'

    self.qry.execute('''UPDATE data_base SET ?=? WHERE atnumber = ?''',(key, value, self.testac))
    self.qry.commit()
```

key and value are dynamically generated based on the field the user wants to edit which is why the SET statement has ?=?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a guess, the `?` syntax is only for parameter binding. That is, inserting the *values* of bound parameters converted appropriately formatted and escaped strings. It's not a general string substitution facility – just use regular string substitution for the column names.

For example, you'd use:

```
key = 'field_a'
value = '01/01/2011'
#self.testac = '010101010'

sql = '''UPDATE data_base SET %(key)s=? WHERE atnumber = ?''' % dict(key=key)
self.qry.execute(sql, (value, self.testac))
```

Comment: Can you mix '?' and string substitutions? Something like: ('''UPDATE data_base SET %s=? WHERE atnumber = ?''',(key,value,self.testac) or in this case would it be better practice to just use string formatting for all of the variables? Thanks!

Comment: Python uses either printf-style syntax (using the `%` operator) or Windows-style extensible syntax (using the `format()` method) for string formatting – neither uses `?` on its own as a special character. (They might or might not clash with SQLite query syntax, but not in your example.)

Comment: @LanceCollins I updated the answer with an example of what I had in mind. I'm using printf-style formatting because I'm more used to it, but it's recommended to use new-style formatting in new code.

Answer (score 2):

The `?` syntax is only for binding value to protect against injection attacks ([example](http://xkcd.com/327/)).

If you are going to take user input for the left side of the `=` you have to make sure to sanitize it your self.  To dynamically generate statements any python string method will work,
but you really shouldn't do this.

A better way would be to have a dictionary of pairs `{key:sql_str}`

```
call_dict = {'col_name':'UPDATE data_base SET col_name=? WHERE atnumber=?'}
self.qry.execute(call_dict[key],(value,self.testac))
```

[edit, fixed typo]